# Boost.asio implement echo server for multiple connections using coroutine

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I've modified a unix socket echo server example from boost.asio official webpage, and adopt it to use coroutines.

I'd like to allow this server handle multiple connections simultaneously.
one solution is to run the method start in class session from background thread, but I preferred coroutines so I've tried to run each listener in a separate spawn. here's my code (compiled version)

notice that in method `server::start` when I tried only one listener it worked, but for multiple sockets it didn't. Perhaps anybody can tell me where did i go wrong ? Thanks !

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>


using namespace std::chrono_literals;

constexpr auto kTimeout = 1s;
#if defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_LOCAL_SOCKETS)

using boost::asio::local::stream_protocol;
using boost::asio::io_context;

class session: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
    session(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
    : socket_(io_context),
    timer_(io_context)
    {
  }

  stream_protocol::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start(const boost::asio::yield_context &yield)
  {
      while (1) {
          auto bytes_read = boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, sizeof(data_)),
                                                    boost::asio::transfer_all(), yield);

          //timer wait to simulate data processing
          timer_.expires_after(kTimeout);
          timer_.async_wait(yield);
          
          auto bytes_transferred = boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                                                            boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_read),
                                                            yield);
      }
  }

private:
  // The socket used to communicate with the client.
  stream_protocol::socket socket_;

  // Buffer used to store data received from the client.
  boost::array<char, 256> data_;

  boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<session> session_ptr;

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_context& ioc, const std::string& file)
    : io_context_(ioc),
      strand_(io_context_.get_executor()),
      acceptor_(strand_, stream_protocol::endpoint(file))
  {

      for (int i=0 ; i < 3; i++) {
          boost::asio::spawn(strand_,
                             [this](const boost::asio::yield_context &yield) {
              session_ptr new_session(new session(this->io_context_));
              
              try {
                  acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(), yield);
                  new_session->start(yield);
              } catch (std::exception &e) {
                  std::cout << "new connection needed: " << e.what() << std::endl;
              }
          });
        }
   }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_context_;
  boost::asio::strand<io_context::executor_type> strand_;
  stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: stream_server <file>\n";
      std::cerr << "*** WARNING: existing file is removed ***\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context ioc;

    std::remove(argv[1]);
    server s(ioc, argv[1]);

    ioc.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}

#else // defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_LOCAL_SOCKETS)
# error Local sockets not available on this platform.
#endif // defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_LOCAL_SOCKETS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want to run 1 accept, and spawn the session only **after** that.

Better yet, you can use the overload of `async_accept` that moves the socket, and specify the strand for the session: you don't need all the sessions to share the same strand that protects the server/acceptor.

Instead of a counted loop, just chain async_accepts:

```
struct Server {
    Server(asio::io_context& ioc, std::string const& file)
        : io_context_(ioc)
        , acceptor_(make_strand(ioc), Protocol::endpoint(file)) //
    {
        accept_loop();
    }

  private:
    asio::io_service&      io_context_;
  //asio::strand<Executor> strand_;
    Protocol::acceptor     acceptor_;

    void accept_loop() {
        acceptor_.async_accept(make_strand(io_context_), [this](error_code ec, Protocol::socket s) {
            if (ec != asio::error::operation_aborted)
                accept_loop();

            std::cout << "Accepted: " << ec.message();
            if (!ec)
                std::cout << " from " << s.remote_endpoint();
            std::cout << std::endl;
        });
    }
};
```

You'll note that I changed some other things around to simplify: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de08cf3768236996)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace std::placeholders;
namespace asio = boost::asio;

constexpr auto kTimeout = 1s;
using Protocol   = asio::local::stream_protocol;
using error_code = boost::system::error_code;

struct Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    Session(Protocol::socket s) : socket_(std::move(s)) {}
    ~Session() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

    void start(asio::yield_context yield) try {
        for (;;) {
            auto n = async_read(socket_, asio::buffer(data_), yield);

            { // simulate work
                asio::steady_timer t(yield.get_executor(), kTimeout);
                t.async_wait(yield);
            }

            n = async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(data_, n), yield);
        }
    } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
        std::cerr << "Session failed: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
    }

  private:
    Protocol::socket      socket_;
    std::array<char, 256> data_;
};

struct Server {
    Server(asio::io_context& ioc, std::string const& file)
        : io_context_(ioc)
        , acceptor_(make_strand(ioc), Protocol::endpoint(file)) //
    {
        accept_loop();
    }

  private:
    asio::io_service&      io_context_;
    Protocol::acceptor     acceptor_;

    void accept_loop() {
        acceptor_.async_accept(make_strand(io_context_), [this](error_code ec, Protocol::socket s) {
            if (ec != asio::error::operation_aborted)
                accept_loop(); // continue accepting new connections

            std::cout << "Accepted: " << ec.message() << std::endl;

            auto strand = s.get_executor(); // copy before move
            spawn(strand, bind(&Session::start, std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(s)), _1));
        });
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) try {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: stream_server <file>\n"
            "*** WARNING: existing file is removed ***\n";
        return 1;
    }

    asio::io_context ioc;

    std::remove(argv[1]);
    Server s(ioc, argv[1]);

    ioc.run();
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

### But, Simplify More!

The whole `shared_ptr` business is just unneeded complication now. After all you have an entire coro frame that can just keep the object alive. In fact, the object is nothing but the socket and the buffer. Just make `Session` a coro: [Live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc1e08cc4aae3ac5)

```
void Session(Protocol::socket& socket, asio::yield_context yield) try {
    std::array<char, 256> data;
    for (;;) {
        auto n = async_read(socket, asio::buffer(data), yield);

        { // simulate work
            asio::steady_timer t(yield.get_executor(), kTimeout);
            t.async_wait(yield);
        }

        n = async_write(socket, asio::buffer(data, n), yield);
    }
} catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
    std::cerr << "Session failed: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
}
```

With

```
spawn(strand, bind(Session, std::move(s), _1));
```

### Side Note

Also, keep in mind that `async_read` already defaults to `transfer_all`. Your approach might be okay IFF you require "messages" of exactly 256 bytes. However, that doesn't seem like an "echo server" to me.

In practice I'd `read_some`:

```
for (;;) {
    auto n = socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(data), yield);

    { // simulate work
        asio::steady_timer t(yield.get_executor(), kTimeout);
        t.async_wait(yield);
    }

    n = async_write(socket, asio::buffer(data, n), yield);
}
```

And, lastly, you want to handle EOF, as it may have partial success:

```
for (boost::system::error_code ec; !ec;) {
    auto n = socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(data), yield[ec]);

    if (n) { // simulate work
        asio::steady_timer t(yield.get_executor(), kTimeout);
        t.async_wait(yield);
    }

    if (!ec || ec == asio::error::eof)
        n = async_write(socket, asio::buffer(data, n), yield);
}
```

Comment: Consider using c++20 coroutines instead (not no more linker dependencies, faster compilation and less runtime overhead): https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61eac493d30a0878